# On being golden

Tags: etymology, idioms, american-english, slang

Saying that *[someone] is golden* means that person is in a desirable situation that will likely lead to some sort of success.

I am trying to find out the origin of this phrase. So far, I have found sites that suggest that:

- [It is used mainly in spoken informal American English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/golden)
- [It may have originated in the military](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1544959)

Does anyone have a more definitive and reputable explanation for the origin of this expression?

Comment: It is not American. https://www.ool.co.uk/blog/the-untimely-death-of-rupert-brooke/ It is used a lot in the UK, especially with "golden boy of" this or that. Lots of areas. Among others you can see on the first google hit: golden boy of British fashion, atheletics, boxing, and on and on and on. Calling someone a golden boy of [something] is a cliché.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, but could it be related to the older *golden boy* and *golden girl*, a successful man and woman, respectively? Quotes from the OED, 2nd edition:

> 1937 C. Odets (title) The *golden
>   boy.  Ibid. iii. i. 196 He walks down
>   the street respected—the golden boy!
>
> 1964 ‘J. Welcome’ Hard to Handle viii.
>   91 Poor dear Richard.+ What a change
>   from being the golden boy of English
>   racing.
>
> 1965 P. Moyes Johnny under Ground xx.
>   250 That would have been the end of
>   Beau Guest, the young chevalier, the
>   golden boy.
>
> 1971 Sunday Times (Johannesburg) 28
>   Mar. 24/1 Ever since he assumed the
>   ‘golden boy’ mantle, Richards has
>   studiously avoided local opposition.

Answer (score 0):

Being golden, as in golden boy / girl, means being successful in ones profession, sports, politics, or even in being a wall street jock / jockette etcetera.

Comment: What the question was asking was when the expression originated, not what it meant.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/433185)